# RFID-RC522 on Arduino Leonardo

Tags: arduino, rfid

I connect the RFID-RC522 to Uno and it works but I connect to Leonardo , it shows the error:

MFRC522 Software Version: 0xFF (unknown)
WARNING: Communication failure, is the MFRC522 properly connected?

I followed the instruction to connect the Arduino (tried use ICSP to replace pin 11-13 )
and use the example of this library :
https://github.com/miguelbalboa/rfid

Comment: Did you changed the arduino board type in IDE?

Comment: Yes, I changed to Leonardo